# ターミナルのls表示における共有フォルダの色

Tags: ubuntu, 端末

Ubuntu 18.04を使用しております．

http://geekna.hatenablog.jp/entry/20130623/p1
上記のページに従ってlsに色がつくように設定しておりましたが，
あるフォルダをローカル共有フォルダに設定したところ，
色が変わってしまい，文字が読みにくくなってしまいました．

以下は，共有フォルダにしたときの設定と現在のlsの状況です．
新しく別のフォルダで共有フォルダの設定の「このフォルダ内でのファイルの作成〜」のチェックを外して
設定をしてみたところ色は変わりませんでした．
すでに色が変わってしまったフォルダの「このフォルダ内でのファイルの作成〜」のチェックを外しても，
色は戻りませんでした．

[image: 共有フォルダの設定]

[image: lsの状況]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ファイル(やフォルダ)の種類や**アクセス権限**によって `ls` 実行時の色が変わるのですが、見えにくくなってしまったフォルダは共有フォルダとして設定した際に「他のユーザに許可する」にチェックをいれたためアクセス権限も変更されており、注意が必要なため背景色が設定された状態です。

共有フォルダの設定を解除した後も上記のアクセス権限はそのままなので、必要に応じて手動で元に戻してください。

- 方法1 (ターミナルからコマンドで実行)

  ```
  $ chmod 755 Desktop
  ```
- 方法2 (GUIでファイラから実行)
  対象のフォルダを右クリックして「プロパティ」を開き、「パーミッション」タブを選択。
  2つ目と3つ目の「フォルダのアクセス権」を「ファイルにアクセスのみ」に変更。
  (以下の画像は Ubuntu Mint での説明なので、若干表記は異なるかもしれません)

  [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]